# PHP / SQL error, unexpected variable name

Tags: php, html, sql

I get the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$studentNo' (T_VARIABLE)
```

Can somebody tell me what's wrong here? I've read about this kind of error and base on it, it usually happens when there's a missing bracket, parenthesis or semi-colon but in my case I don't think I missed any..Does it have something to do with the variable itself, perhaps?

```
if(isset($_POST['next'])){
        $studentNo = $_POST['sn'];
        if(!empty($_POST['sn'])){
            $check =  ("SELECT * FROM student_info WHERE SN="$studentNo"");
            $check1 = mysqli_query($con, $check);
            if(mysql_num_rows($check1) > 0){
                $errors['sn'] = "Student number already exists";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Fix this line, `$check =  "SELECT * FROM student_info WHERE SN='$studentNo'";` unnesessary parenthesis at start and end. Also use single quotes on `$studentNo` variable

Comment: And next time *BE SURE TO TAKE NOTE OF THE LINE#!!!!!*  The error message will include the line#; the line# will take you right to the error.  ALSO: consider using prepared statements: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html

Comment: @AlwaysSunny You can keep variable names like that? I thought he needed to concatenate the strings.

Comment: @Anvay I thought he can use single quotes also

Comment: @AlwaysSunny Oh, I didn't know that.

Comment: `mysql_num_rows` won't work with `mysqli_query`. You need all `mysqli` functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you have to concatenate the string.

But, before doing this, make sure that your SQL library protects against SQL injections.

To do this, just do:

```php
$check = "SELECT * FROM student_info WHERE SN=" . $studentNo . ";";

// Also, remember to add a semicolon at the end of your SQL query :)
```

The best way to do this is to use a prepared statement. [This site](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp#:%7E:text=A%20prepared%20statement%20is%20a,statements%20basically%20work%20like%20this%3A&text=The%20database%20parses%2C%20compiles%2C%20and,the%20result%20without%20executing%20it) explains it very well.

Comment: You're correct.  But an even *better* approach would be to use a prepared statement.  Otherwise the OP is wide-open to a  [SQL Injection attack](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html)

Comment: @Anvay thanks!! it worked, sorry for the noob question, im new to php, i appreciate your help!!!

Comment: remove unnecessary parenthesis at start and end along with a semicolon

Comment: @paulsm4 Yes. Except I've never used SQL with PHP, so I don't know how to do that in PHP :)

Comment: @AlwaysSunny, oh yeah, didn't even notice those parentheses

Comment: Semi-colons for SQL aren't required in PHP (or at least with `mysqli` and `pdo` for the mysql db).

Comment: @user3783243 Oh, I didn't know that.